# conditional execution in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile:

```
C_FILE=""
cfg: 
    ## C to CFG ####
    @ echo $(C_FILE)
    ifndef C_FILE
    $(error variable C_FILE not set)
    endif
    $(eval CFG_FILE := ./outputs/temp/$(shell basename $(C_FILE) .c).cfg)
    gcc -fdump-tree-cfg=$(CFG_FILE) $(C_FILE)
```

When I run the command `make cfg C_FILE="./inputs/Fib.c"` it always
terminates saying variable `C_FILE` not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines beginning with a tab character (by default) aren't parsed by make (other than for variable expansion), they're sent directly to the shell, get rid of the indents on the lines with the make conditionals

```
C_FILE=""
cfg: 
    ## C to CFG ####
    @ echo $(C_FILE)
ifndef C_FILE
    $(error variable C_FILE not set)
endif
    $(eval CFG_FILE := ./outputs/temp/$(shell basename $(C_FILE) .c).cfg)
    gcc -fdump-tree-cfg=$(CFG_FILE) $(C_FILE)
```

Comment: There is a problem.
There is  a rule called "clean" in the makefile. Now that rule is not working. It says `C_FILE` not defined.

Comment: @KulwantSingh I can't help you if you don't post the complete file.

Comment: The condition needs to be put in a separate rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some comments to user657267's answer.

- `ifndef C_FILE` is always false. C_FILE is defined on the first line, or from command line. Consider using `ifeq "" "$(C_FILE)"`.
- Quote (`"`) is normal character in makefile. Define empty variable this way:

  ```
  C_FILE=
  ```
- instead of using `$(shell )` function, use [makefile built-ins](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions):

  ```
  $(basename $(notdir $(C_FILE)))
  ```
- avoid using `$(eval )` if not really needed. Extract relevant code outside recipe.

My proposal is:

```
C_FILE=

ifeq "" "$(C_FILE)"
 $(error variable C_FILE not set)
endif
CFG_FILE=./outputs/temp/$(basename $(notdir $(C_FILE))).cfg

cfg:
    ## C to CFG ####
    @ echo $(C_FILE)
    gcc -fdump-tree-cfg=$(CFG_FILE) $(C_FILE)
```